# flutter : login buton logs in user but the next home page doesnt show up

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

the sign in code auth.dart

```
Future signInEmailPassword(LoginUser _login) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _login.email.toString(),
              password: _login.password.toString());
      User? user = userCredential.user;
      return _firebaseUser(user!);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return FirebaseUser(code: e.code, uid: null);
    }
  }
```

the login button code in login.dart

```
final loginEmailPasswordButon = Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () async {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
          
             dynamic result = await _auth.signInEmailPassword(LoginUser(email:_email.text, password:_password.text));
              if (result.uid == null) { //null means unsuccessfull authentication
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: Text(result.code),
                        // actions: [Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Wrapper()))],
                      );
                    });
          }
          }
        },
        child: Text(
          "Log in",
          style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

login button called in scaffold:

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login Demo Page'),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                  emailField,
                  const SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  passwordField,
                  txtbutton,
                  const SizedBox(height: 35.0),
                  loginEmailPasswordButon,
                  const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

loginuser.dart

```
class LoginUser {
  final String? email;
  final String? password;

  LoginUser({this.email, this.password});
}
```

debug console:

```
D/FirebaseAuth( 6407): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth( 6407): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.  // here i am on login screen now after signout

════════ Exception caught by provider ══════════════════════════════════════════
An exception was throw by _MapStream<User?, FirebaseUser?> listened by
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2  
W/System  ( 6407): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. // now i try login below
D/FirebaseAuth( 6407): Notifying id token listeners about user ( PJ6EcBACJ4UBsMbU8ehHkvRGeit1 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 6407): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( PJ6EcBACJ4UBsMbU8ehHkvRGeit1 ).
```

on filling user credentials, the login page remains as it is, no next home page. if i remove app from recent apps on emulator and start it again, it shows logged in, that is the login process itself worked, but didnt take me to next screen instantly.
the register has very similar code but works fine.

register button code:

```
    final registerButton = Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () async {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              dynamic result = await _auth.registerEmailPassword(LoginUser(email: _email.text,password: _password.text));
               if (result.uid == null) { //null means unsuccessfull authentication
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: Text(result.code),
                        actions: [],
                      );
                    });
          }
          }
        },
        child: Text(
          "Register",
          style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

here in register page also the else condition for `if (result.uid == null)`  is not used and it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't added code for routing in `onPressed` function of your `loginEmailPasswordButon`  button. Add routing code in else condition.

```
  onPressed: () async {
        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
          dynamic result = await _auth.signInEmailPassword(
              LoginUser(email: _email.text, password: _password.text));
          if (result.uid == null) {
            //null means unsuccessfull authentication
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    content: Text(result.code),
                    // actions: [Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Wrapper()))],
                  );
                });
          } else {
            // else it's successful and navigate to Home Screen - Add routing here 
          }
        }
      },
```